# Remove space between article <header> and <p>

Tags: css, html

I can't seem to figure out why there's a large space around the `<p>` tag here. Can someone point out my folly?

```
/** article stuff **/
    article {padding:5px;margin-bottom:5px;}
    article * header {margin:0;padding:0;}
    article * h4 {margin:0;}
    article * span {font-size:xx-small;vertical-align:top;}
    article * p {padding:0;margin:0 auto;clear:both;}
    article * a, a:link {font-size:x-small;}
```

```
<article>
    <header>
        <h4>@article.Title</h4>
        <span><strong>@article.Category</strong>: <time pubdate datetime="@article.PublishDate">@article.PublishDate.ToShortDateString()</time></span>
    </header>
    <p>@article.Description</p>
    <a href="@article.Url" title="@article.Title">Read more...</a>
</article>
```

doing it this way leaves a large gap around the `<p>` between the header and the read more link. How do I get rid of that space?

http://jsfiddle.net/72LX8/

PS - My html/css is still pretty rusty, so no jabs at it please. Just looking for an answer. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `*` in your rules. Just `article p`. By leaving it in, you're actually making a rule that looks for an article element, then any element, and then a paragraph.
**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/72LX8/3/)**

Comment: Oh for *$%@%# sake.... thank ya sir... ;) - have to wait a few mins before it will let me accept.

Comment: To expand on this, while `*` will perform globbing maybe the way you would expect (match any element), something like `article p` will match _any_ p that is a descendant of an article. No need to account for the stuff in between.